# Hexagonal - number of cells

Tags: matrices

For $n = 2$;

We have something like this:

https://zapodaj.net/0cc6e3c190f32.png.html

and number of  calls is equal **7**.

But how designate for $n$ ?

For $n = 3$;

we have **19**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite badly stated, but... if you're just asking for the number of hexagons when you add layers (and keep the shape hexagonal), then it's pretty obvious, the first layer adds $6$ hexagons, the next adds $2\times 6$ hexagons and so on, so in total, you have
$$6\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1=3n^2-3n+1$$

Comment: I mean number of ceils in hexagon

Comment: You're arranging small hexagons (cells) into a larger hexagon. I stand by my answer.

Comment: nope, for n = 3 we have 19

Comment: look my question

Comment: $3\times 3^2-3\times 3+1=19$